# How to get host uptime in solaris using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, solaris

I would like to get system uptime in solaris. On linux I would do it like this:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

long long get_host_uptime()
{
    struct sysinfo memInfo;
    sysinfo( &memInfo );
    return memInfo.uptime;
}
```

I would like to find some analog of `sysinfo` for solaris as well.

Comment: have a look at some of the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661006/getting-the-uptime-of-a-sunos-unix-box-in-seconds-only

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Do you know if the `getutxent()` answer to the question you linked works in a zone?  I'd think not, but I don't have access to a Solaris box right now to test.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker thanks but those answers miss the "using C++" part :)

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan : that's why I didn't mark it as a duplicate. That said, the other question shows several approaches - some of which can easily be used from C++ (including the current top answer with C code, and the several answers with the kstat approach which can be done using libkstat from C++ eg.).